# Finding sum of the series $\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r)(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, partial-fractions

Find the sum: $$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r)(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)}$$

**My method:**

I tried to split it into partial fractions like: $\dfrac{A}{r}, \dfrac{B}{r+d}$ etc. Using this method, we have **4 equations** in $A,B,C,D$! And solving them takes much time. I split into partial fractions hoping that some of them will cancel out and the sum might telescope.

I hope theres a simpler method to this.

**Edit**

As a **side-question**, can we extend this to $k$ factors in denominator, something like

$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(r)(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)...(r+(k-1)d)}$$

Using N.S answer, we can extend it easily:

$$= \dfrac{1}{(k-1)d}\left(\frac{1}{r(r+d)...(r+(k-2)d)} - \frac{1}{(r+d)(r+2d)...(r+(k-1)d)}\right)$$

Comment: is $d \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @RabMakh Yes $d$ is a natural number.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my question and solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2424036/168053).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> And solving them takes much time.

There is a trick so solving partial fractions quickly.

$$\frac{1}{(r)(r + d)(r + 2d)(r + 3d)}
=
\frac{A}{r} + \frac{B}{r + d} + \frac{C}{r + 2d} + \frac{D}{r + 3d}$$

$$1 
=
A(r + d)(r + 2d)(r + 3d) + 
B(r)(r + 2d)(r + 3d) +
C(r)(r + d)(r + 3d) + 
D(r)(r + d)(r + 2d)$$

The above is true for all $r$.  So plug in the roots of the original equation.  $r = 0$ gives:

$$1 = A(d)(2d)(3)$$
$$A = \frac{1}{6d^3}$$

Then $r = -d$ :

$$1 = B(-d)(d)(2d)$$
$$B = \frac{-1}{2d^3}$$

Then $r = -2d$:

$$1 = C(-2d)(-d)(d)$$
$$C = \frac{1}{2d^3}$$

Last $r = -3d$:

$$1 = D(-3d)(-2d)(-d)$$
$$D = \frac{-1}{6d^3}$$

So you get:

$$S = \frac{1}{6d^3}\left( \frac{1}{r} - \frac{3}{r + d} + \frac{3}{r + 2d} - \frac{1}{r + 3d}\right)$$

After you do it a few times and get the pattern, you can almost do it in your head.  I suggest looking at it as 2 telescoping series:

$$\text{Sum} = \left(\frac{1}{6d^3} \sum_{r = 1}^n \frac{1}{r} - \frac{1}{r + 3d}\right) + 
 \left(\frac{-1}{2d^3} \sum_{r = 1}^n \frac{1}{r + d} - \frac{1}{r + 2d}\right)$$

Comment: That was neat!.

Comment: I like your method of solving! This will surely come in handy! Thanks :)

Comment: This approach is how I learned it, from a 1940s math book.

Comment: I think its similar to [Heaviside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_cover-up_method) cover up rule. I keep forgetting this!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{1}{(r)(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)}=\frac{1}{3d}\left(\frac{1}{(r)(r+d)(r+2d)}-\frac{1}{(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)}\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Using this approach its very easy to extend to more factors :)

Answer (score 2):

When computing a partial fraction decomposition one can always invoke residues. In our case
$$ f(x)=\frac{1}{x(x+d)(x+2d)(x+3d)} = \frac{A_0}{x}+\frac{A_1}{x+d}+\frac{A_2}{x+2d}+\frac{A_3}{x+3d} $$
and 
$$ A_k = \text{Res}\left(f(x),x=-kd\right) = \lim_{x\to -kd}(x+kd)\,f(x)=\frac{1}{\prod_{\substack{0\leq j\leq 3 \\ j\neq k}}(-kd+jd)}$$
so $(A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3)$ is proportional to $\left(+\binom{3}{0},-\binom{3}{1},+\binom{3}{2},-\binom{3}{3}\right)$.
This approach has a great generality and it clearly shows that the coefficients appearing in the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{1}{x(x+d)\cdots(x+Md)}$ are proportional to the binomial coefficients $\binom{M}{k}$ took with alternating signs.

Comment: Nice solution, as always! (+1). I was about to comment that the coefficients look very familiar :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but what does residue mean here?

Comment: @akhmeteni: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)

Comment: @Jack Actually I am in school, so I don't understand that stuff. Is there an easier introduction to that subject?

Comment: @akhmeteni: you may simply ignore the $\text{Res}$ part and read $A_k = \lim_{x \to -kd}(x+kd)\,f(x)$. The above solution still makes sense and you completely avoid complex analysis.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\frac{1}{r(r+d)(r+2d)(r+3d)} = \frac{1}{2d^2}\left(\frac{1}{r(r+3d)}-\frac{1}{(r+d)(r+2d)}\right) = \frac{1}{6d^3}\left(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+3d}\right)-\frac{1}{2d^3}\left(\frac{1}{r+d}-\frac{1}{r+2d}\right).$$

Comment: Thanks! How did you get this idea of splitting like that?

Comment: @akhmeteni you can further go as $\frac{1}{r(r+3d)} = \frac{1}{3d}(\frac{1}{r}-\frac{1}{r+3d})$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

(Modified answer)

Define $r^{\overline{m}(d)}$ as the $d$-tuple rising factorial, i.e. 
$r^{\overline{m}(d)}=r(r+d)(r+2d)\cdots(r+(m-1)d) $ 
and $r^{-\overline{m}(d)}=\frac 1{r^{\overline{m}(d)}}$
, e.g. $r^{\overline{4}(3)}=r(r+3)(r+6)(r+9)$.

$$\begin{align}
S(m,d)&=\sum_{r=1}^n\frac 1{r(r+d)(r+2d)\cdots (r+(m-1)d)}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^n r^{-\overline{m}(d)}\\
&=\frac 1{(m-1)d}\sum_{r=1}^n r^{-\overline{m-1}(d)}\ -\ (r+d)^{-\overline{m-1}(d)}\\
&=\boxed{\frac 1{(m-1)d}\sum_{r=1}^d  r^{-\overline{m-1}(d)}\ - (n+r)^{-\overline{m-1}(d)} }
\end{align}$$

For example, if $d=3, m=4, n=100$, 
$$\small\begin{align}
&S(3,4)\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^{100}\frac 1{r(r+3)(r+6)(r+9)}\\
&\color{lightgrey}{=\small\frac 1{1\cdot 4\cdot7\cdot 10}
+\frac 1{2\cdot5\cdot8\cdot 11}+\frac 1{3\cdot6\cdot9\cdot 12}
+\cdots+
\frac 1{100\cdot103\cdot106\cdot109}
}\\
&=\frac 19 \sum_{r=1}^{100}\frac 1{r(r+3)(r+6)}-\frac 1{(r+3)(r+6)(r+9)}\\
&=\frac 19\left[ \sum_{r=1}^{100}\frac 1{r(r+3)(r+6)}-\sum_{r=4}^{103}\frac 1{r(r+3)(r+6)}\right]\\
&=\frac 19\left[ \sum_{r=1}^3 \frac1{r(r+3)(r+6)}-\sum_{r=101}^{103}\frac 1{r(r+3)(r+6)(r+9)}\right]\\
&=\small\frac 19 \left[\frac 1{1\cdot 4\cdot7\cdot}
+\frac 1{2\cdot5\cdot8}+\frac 1{3\cdot6\cdot9}
-\frac 1{101\cdot 104\cdot 107}
-\frac 1{102\cdot 105\cdot 108}
-\frac 1{103\cdot106\cdot 109}
\right]\end{align}$$

Comment: Nice generalisation of the result! Than you a lot!

Comment: Thanks! Some minor edits.

Comment: I do not see why the second equality is true. The sum doesn't appear to telescope unless $d = 1$. For general $d$, the second term is not a shift of $r$ by $1$, it is a shift of $r$ by $d$, which doesn't line up with the fact we increment $r$ by $1$.

Comment: I have also checked numerically whether this holds for $d \in \mathbb R$ and $d \in \mathbb N$ and unless I am making a coding error it does not.

Comment: @guy - Thanks for pointing that out. The original answer holds for $d=1$. I have posted a modified answer which should hold for a general $d\in \mathbb N^+$.